# iOS: Not showing launch view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, splash-screen

I added the launch images in the target settings as shown in this picture:
[image]

When I click the little eye icons, the correct image shows.

The images are in the project root.

But, they don't display when I try it in the simulator or on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tri to cancel and reinstall the app on the simulator

Comment: Thanks! It worked (at least on the simulator - haven't tried it on the device yet; had to wait 10 mins to accept your answer)